# Conditional types

Tags: conditional-constructions

I know there exist three main types of conditionals: first type (real present or future); second type (unreal present); third type (unreal past). And talking about second type we understand it as a "dream"as well as third means "regret" about something we shouldn't have done in the past.

There are also three mixed types: condition 2 - main clause 3 (unreal, condition reffers to indefinite time, main clause - to certain past time); condition 3 - main clause 2 (unreal, condition - in the past, main part - present); condition 2 - main part 1. Doing test I was confused with one statement:

> Hellen is bossy. She acts as if she owned the place.

I thought it is the right answer but still don't know is it mixed type 3 and if it is so, could you explain to me to what type reffers condition, main clause and what is its type (real/unreal) as we have two different parts. Types 2 and 3 are both unreal so there is no confusion. But in the case above.

Comment: The "first, second, third, etc conditionals" are not linguistically meaningful categories, just pedagogical crutches to help learners get a primitive grasp of conditionals. You seem to have mastered enough English to throw away the crutches and walk on your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a side note to StoneyB's excellent answer: There are [many English idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/if) that include the word "if".  Many of these are not really *conditional* expressions but rather variations on other, simple phrases:

> "As if" = "like" : "He looks **as if** he's going to run away"
>
> "Don't mind if I do" = "I will" : "Would you like another cup of coffee?" "**Don't mind if I do.**"
>
> "If nothing else" = "for no other reason" : "Taking a walk every day will, **if nothing else**, get you away from the computer for a few hours"
>
> "If you please" = "Please" : "Help me clear away the dishes from the table, **if you please**?"

And many more.  Again as StoneyB mentions you could imagine a conditional in all of these, but it's not a very useful exercise.  Instead it's more useful to simply recognize their underlying meaning when you see them.

Side note:  You're also mixing verb tenses in your example sentence.  It (normally) should be either,

> She acted as if she owned the place

or

> She acts as if she owns the place

However, native speakers also make this kind of mistake, so it's more about good *style* than perfect *grammar*.  [More information on verb consistency](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/tenseconsistency.htm)

Answer (score 7):

> She acts as if she owned the place.

This isn't a conditional at all.

Conditional constructions have the general form "If P, then Q", with a condition clause (protasis or *if* clause) subordinated to a consequence clause (*then* clause (apodosis or *then* clause—but more often than not the *then* is omitted).

In your sentence, however, there is no condition clause. *As if* is complicated  (many constructions with *as* are complicated!),<sup>†</sup> but it's fundamentally a comparative construction functioning in this case as an adverbial complement to *acts*

> She acts impulsively.
>   She acts in this manner.
>   She acts like this.
>   She acts like she owns the place.

You might argue that a conditional construction underlies the *as if* clause:

> ***as*** she would act [this way] if she owned the place.

But this subordinated conditional contains both the condition clause and the (deleted) consequence clause; the matrix clause *she acts ...* plays no role in the conditional construction.

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>There's a lengthy discussion of *as if / as though* in Huddleston and Pullum, *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, 1151-2; they take these phrases to be compound prepositions.</sub>