# Mixed conditionals

Tags: conditional-constructions

I know there exist three main types of conditionals:

1. real present or future (if clause: Present Simple, Present
   Continuos,    Present Perfect; main clause: Future Simple or can,
   may, might, must    + bare infinitive);
2. unreal present or future (if clause: Past Simple, Past Continuos;
   main clause: would, could, might + bare infinitive);
3. unreal past (if clause: Past Perfect, Past Perfect Continuous; main
   clause: would, could, might + Past Participle).

And talking about second type we understand it as a "dream"as well as third means "regret" about something we shouldn't have done in the past. In the first case it is something like "plans'.

There are also three mixed types:

1. condition 2 - main clause 3 (unreal, condition reffers to indefinite
   time, main clause - to certain past time);
2. condition 3 - main clause 2 (unreal, condition - in the past, main
   part - present);
3. condition 2 - main part 1.

Could you explain to me what type condition and main clause reffer to (condition reffers to type 2 and main part - type 1)? And what is its type (real/unreal) as we have two different parts. Types 2 and 3 are both unreal so there is no confusion. But in the case above. I would like you to explain to me on this example:

```
"If nobody phoned him, he won't come to the meeting".
```

Comment: You understand that only English teachers and professional linguists use this kind of language to describe parts of speech.  Without more information I don't know what you mean by "condition 2 - main part 1" since this relates only to how you, personally, are taught English and not to how English speakers form sentences.

Comment: There are no mixed conditionals with unreal past in the condition and future in the result that I know of. These are the only two types of mixed conditionals: http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv344.shtml The only example that comes to mind -- though it is not a mixed conditional -- is "If I *should see* her, *I'll give* her your message". However, "should" there is not conditional and merely means: "If (by any chance) I happen to see her..."

Comment: By the way, didn't these answers convince you?: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/121433/conditional-types

Comment: The usual teaching of "first, second, third, &c conditionals" does not clearly distinguish form and modality. By "condition 2 - main part 1" do you mean a conditional consisting of **1) the protasis** (condition clause) headed by a verb in past-tense form and **2) the apodosis** (consequence clause) headed by a verb in present-tense form?

Comment: @Andrew, I have rewritten it and improwed it.

Comment: @Gustavson, you example shows the 1st type of conditionals. It has been taken from native literature.

Comment: @StoneyB, yes. I should have written it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike mixed conditionals combining conditionals type 2 and 3, in which the condition is, as you say, unreal, the condition in "If nobody **phoned** him, he won't come to the meeting" is real.

That sentence can be expanded into an ordinary conditional type 1 sentence, with present in the condition and future in the result:

- If it **is** a fact / If it **is** true that nobody phoned him, then he won't come to the meeting.

Here's another example:

- If you **didn't study**, you **won't pass** the exam.

Another mixed conditional you haven't mentioned but is also possible is the one combining present perfect (or even past) in the condition and present in the result:

- If you **haven't seen** that movie, you **don't/can't know** what a good movie is.
- If you **didn't attend** yesterday's introductory lesson, you **are wasting** your time here today.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I need. Good and clear explanation with examples.

Comment: @AnthonyVoronkov I'm happy to have been of help. That example you provided was crucial for me to understand what you meant by mixing conditionals type 1 and 2